# Завершение программы в Ruby

Tags: ruby

кто подскажет, как заставить руби прекратить выполнение программы. К примеру, задача с арбузами. Я ввожу кол-во арбузов, что хочу купить и есть условие

```
if amount <= 0 
# как-то завершить код
```

Я раньше использовал C и там подобное делалось с помощью return 0. Как это сделать в руби?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таким образом:

```
 abort

 # или так:

 abort "Сообщение о завершении"
```